# How to create a url for row in database ("<td>" .$row["website"] ."</td>";)

Tags: php, sql, arrays, url

I have created a database in phpMyAdmin and I have 10 rows of data and each row has a column to show its website address. I want to make the website address clickable.

I used the below array method to show my website address link, but it doesn't work

```
    $website = array(
    array("Google","https://code.tutsplus.com"),
    array("Bing","https://weatherstack.com"),
    array("W3","https://www.w3schools.com")
   
    );

    foreach ($website as $urlitem){ 
    echo "<a href='".$urlitem[1]."'></a>";
    }

    

    // this gets an associative array (ie the keys can be used as well as the indicies)
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){


   // The below code displays my table


        echo "<tr>";
         
        echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['type'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['street'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['city'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['region'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['code'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td><a href='".$urlitem[0]."'>" .$row["website"] ."</td>";
       

        echo "</tr>";            
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `foreach` loop, the issue is you are not print out anything to be displayed for anchor tag. Means you anchor tag exists but it does not have any content to be shown on html;

```
<a href="">YOUR CONTENT MISSING PART</a>
```

After that in your `while` loop, you are using the variable `$urlitem` which does not exists. You either need to declared it outside your `foreach` or need to use the `$website` variable to get the `url`.